# Extract bezier curve info from a TTF file (ttfquery won't install)

Tags: python, truetype

I saw this post: [Retrieving bounding box and bezier curve data for all glyphs in a .ttf font file in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40437308/retrieving-bounding-box-and-bezier-curve-data-for-all-glyphs-in-a-ttf-font-file)

about how to retrieve the bezier curve data from a TTF file. The reason I want this is so that I can make animations of letters being drawn in matplotlib. The problem is that the package ttfquery won't install. My guess is that my python version is too new (3.9) and that package is pretty old.

```
C:\Users\Chris>pip install TTFQuery
Collecting TTFQuery
  Downloading TTFQuery-1.0.5.tar.gz (17 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [7 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
        File "C:\Users\Chris\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-djyaq0d_\ttfquery_678fb4fdd4004a81b1bc72c29a99b35f\setup.py", line 11
          except ImportError, err:
                            ^
      SyntaxError: invalid syntax
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```

Is there another way to obtain that sort of info from a TTF file? Alternatively, is there a way to specifically obtain the stroke order of Japanese characters that can be downloaded for free?

I ultimately want to make animations such as [this](https://jisho.org/search/%E9%9A%8E%20%23kanji) one. Is there some free tool/ data online for that sort of purpose or do I have to install an earlier python version and use that instead?

Comment: The `ttfdump` program (I got it with my TeXLive install in the `ttfutils` package) can dump glyphs from a truetype font.

Comment: the website doesn't respond after uploading the togoshi-mincho.ttf. Maybe it doesn't work for japanese ttfs bc they're too large or something.

Comment: I downloaded the font and tried it with `ttfdump`. It works. But e.g. just the `glyf` table output for that font is 207 MiB.

Comment: could it be that it just takes a while and that my browser might be bad for this purpose? I use Brave. mozilla doesn't work either for me.

Comment: If I redirect the output to a file, dumping the glyf table takes less than a second. Without knowing how the website works, it's impossible to say why it doesn't work.

Comment: Well there are many libraries. I recommend ```freetype-py```. See the official example, [glyph-vector](https://github.com/rougier/freetype-py/blob/master/examples/glyph-vector.py).

Comment: ttfquery 1.0.5 is prety old https://pypi.org/project/TTFQuery/#history . You can try install the newer beta version `pip install TTFQuery==2.0.0b1`

Comment: See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74988456/1186624) on that old question.